# I can't seem to get the value I want from UIStepper

Tags: ios4, uiview

I am using iOS 5.0 and I'm trying to get a value from my UIStepper.

I set the minimum to 0.0
The maximum is 25.0
The step value is 1.0

The starting value is 15.0

If I tap the + button ten times, the + will grey out so I know I'm at the max.

I've wired the "value changed" event in the uistepper to an IBAction called stepulate

That method only has an NSLog

Looks like

```
NSLog(@"%d", [myStepper value]);
```

I keep getting zero printed. No matter how many times I tap the + or - button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIStepper uses a float for its value. Try this:

```
NSlog(@"Stepper Value: %.f", [stepper value]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double stepperValue = rating_pound_stepper.value;
    self.lbl_pound_rating.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", stepperValue];
```

Answer (score -2):

try 
NSLog(@"%d", [myStepper intValue]);

Comment: I'm sure that UiStepper doesn't respond to IntValue. UIStepper only has a property called value